# Can't build iOS app with phonegap build

Tags: ionic-framework, phonegap-build

When i try to build my app for iOS i am getting an error which says

> Error - The following core plugin is causing the build to fail and may need to be updated to a newer version: camera

Comment: Which version of phonegap are you using ? It seems a bit outdated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your plugin reference in PhoneGap config.xml to the one shown below:

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-camera" spec="https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera.git"/>
```

Please refer to this thread for more details: https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2190271